# Add RcppParallel requisites to the NAMESPACE of an R package automatically when compiling the package

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package, rcpparmadillo, rcppparallel

I'm using `RcppParallel` in my own R package.

I know that I need to add `Imports: RcppParallel` to the `DESCRIPTION` file and `importFrom(RcppParallel, RcppParallelLibs)` to the `NAMESPACE` file.

My current workflow to compile my R package is:

1. run `Rcpp::compileAttributes()`
2. run `devtools::document()`
3. manually add `importFrom(RcppParallel, RcppParallelLibs)` to the `NAMESPACE` file
4. run `devtools::install("MyPackage",quick = T,upgrade="never")`

My question is what changes should I make to my R package, so that I can skip the manual step 3? I already add `Imports: RcppParallel` to the `DESCRIPTION` file and why does `importFrom(RcppParallel, RcppParallelLibs)` not show up in the `NAMESPACE` file after step 2?

Comment: You could read the documentation of the roxygen2 package because it lets you write to NAMESPACE programmatically.  Starting with `RcppParallel::RcppParallel.package.skeleton()` should also set you up correctly--as that is what the function is for.  Or maybe do not run `devtools::document()` if does things you do not like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of your C++ source files add this to an existing entry

```
//' @importFrom RcppParallel RcppParallelLibs
```

When you run `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` this gets carried over to an R file where the `roxygen2` package, when running in 'full mode' also rewriting `NAMESPACE` will add the entry.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `devtools` package for this. Each package you want to add to your own package add the command `use_package`

```
library(devtools)
use_package("RcppParallelw", min_version = T)
```

The `use_package` function will automatically add any entries needed in `DESCRIPTION` for you.
Additionally, the `min_version = T` option will ensure that your package requires `RcppParallelw` at a version not lower than you currently have installed.

Comment: That's all very nice but it doesn't address the question asked.